# d3.js concentric force layout example

Tags: layout, d3.js, force-layout

Is there a way to configure the gravity in a force layout to make the bubbles align concentric around a center?

something like in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR5EW.jpg

I was looking for an example, but couldn't find one yet.

Comment: You'll have to determine the values for your specific case.

Comment: so it is possible changing the values.

Comment: Well of course, see [the API documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout).